# py2exe: not able to make exe with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, py2exe

I have problem to create running exe with program using pandas.

If I run the program as py then it works.
I am even able to create succesfully an exe file but it doesn't work.

Error: no module named skiplist (skiplist.pxd)

Do you have any Idea how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: You might need to include pandas in the py2exe options in setup. See the "includes" option here: http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/ListOfOptions.

Comment: Same problem, did you solve it?